# In BottomDialogFragment I have the making Draggble false but its getting warning message

Tags: java, android

Is getting below warning when I open bottomDialogFragemnt and it's drag and dismiss when we slide scroll right or left side on BottomDialogFragment and no other information details in Logcat of the android studio.

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field mBehavior in class 
    Landroid/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialog; (declaration of 
   'android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetDialog' )
System.err:     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Native Method)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.onGetLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:330)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performGetLayoutInflater(Fragment.java:1308)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6816)
System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1565)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1453)
```

I have written below code in BottoDialogFragment:

```
//      Log.i(TAG, "dragging()");
            Field mBehaviorField = bottomSheetDialog.getClass().getDeclaredField("mBehavior");
            mBehaviorField.setAccessible(true);
            final BottomSheetBehavior behavior =
                    (BottomSheetBehavior) mBehaviorField.get(bottomSheetDialog);
            behavior.setHideable(false);
```

And also used below move event of BottomDialogFragment:

```
/*Back press event fire*/
        bottomSheetDialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(android.content.DialogInterface dialog,
                                 int keyCode, android.view.KeyEvent event) {

                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    // To dismiss the fragment when the back-button is pressed.
                    Log.i(TAG, "onKey:KEYCODE_BACK ");
                    if (isRecordAudioAdd) {
                        if (mFilename != null && mFilename.length() > 0 && RecTime != 0) {
                            openDialog(mFilename, RecTime);
                        } else {
                            dismissAllowingStateLoss();
                        }
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        dismissAllowingStateLoss();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                /*// Otherwise, do nothing else
                else return false;*/
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: error says in this line  `bottomSheetDialog.getClass().getDeclaredField("mBehavior");` didnot find `mBehavior` field

Comment: But when run the App in Debug Mode its work perfectly generated this warning in Release App run. Why should happen this i can't understand?

Comment: if you are going to setState on BottomSheetDialogFragment, then this will help you.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35937453/set-state-of-bottomsheetdialogfragment-to-expanded/37473551

Comment: i'll try to apply this. Thank you @KrishnaVyas

Comment: this is not working  @Krishna Vyas

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution of this warning message :

```
 /* ************** dragging off******************* */
    try {
        //      Log.i(TAG, "dragging()");
        Field mBehaviorField = bottomSheetDialog.getClass().getDeclaredField("behavior");
        mBehaviorField.setAccessible(true);
        final BottomSheetBehavior behavior =
                (BottomSheetBehavior) mBehaviorField.get(bottomSheetDialog);
        behavior.setHideable(false);

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

update the behavior as `bottomSheetDialog.getClass().getDeclaredField("mBehavior");` to `bottomSheetDialog.getClass().getDeclaredField("behavior");`