# How can I keep a BottomSheetDialogFragment height to always match_parent?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet

I'm having trouble with a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` I implemented some days back in a project I'm in.
What happens is that I have a `BottomSheet` which contains a `SearchView` and a `Recyclerview`. The dialog fragment shows correctly and stuff, all good there.
The problem starts when I use the `SearchView` to filter the `Recyclerview`'s results since when there's 5 or less results, the keyboard is overlapping the now small `Recyclerview`.
I want to know if it's possible to keep the `BottomSheet` height as `match_parent` or something to fill the window or keep the `Recyclerview` big enough to avoid the keyboard "messing up" with the results. I use the following method to make the fragment expanded when it opens:

```
private fun expandBottomSheet() {
    view?.viewTreeObserver?.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
        val dialog = dialog as BottomSheetDialog

        val bottomSheet = dialog.findViewById<View>(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet)

        val behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from<View>(bottomSheet)

        behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
    }

}
```

And my XML for the sheet is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

    <View
        android:layout_width="52dp"
        android:layout_height="7dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_small_4"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/size_small_4"
        android:background="@drawable/border_top_swipe_indicator" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        app:queryHint="@string/text_type_your_query" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/border_top_white"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:listitem="@layout/list_item" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

**Edit:**
The bottom sheet containing the `Recyclerview` and stuff is a child fragment (a fragment instantiated from another fragment.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I'm not satisfied with the fix I came up to, I have to say it's working smoothly.
Basically I wrapped my `bottomsheet` with a `ViewPager` and it's not resizing.
I admit this is a hack and I'm hoping someone can provide a more decent answer to this. In the meantime, `ViewPager` with a single `bottomsheet` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is searching for this question, if you want to force your `BottomSheetDialogFragment` have full screen height, just wrap your bottom sheet content layout inside of this custom FrameLayout:

```
public class MatchParentFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {
    public MatchParentFrameLayout(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MatchParentFrameLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MatchParentFrameLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public MatchParentFrameLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        if (MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec) == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        }
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height with the below code in On Activity created

```
view?.viewTreeObserver?.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
            val rect = Rect()
            view?.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect)
            val screenHeight = view?.rootView?.height
            val keyPadHeight = screenHeight?.minus(rect.bottom)

            if (screenHeight != null) {
                if (keyPadHeight != 0) {
                    if (view?.paddingBottom != keyPadHeight) {
                        view?.setPadding(0, 0, 0, keyPadHeight!!)
                    }
                } else {
                    if (view?.paddingBottom != 0) {
                        view?.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)
                    }
                }
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

In the manifest.xml file you have your activities declared there for your application. Inside of the `<activity>` block where this bottom sheet is hosted you can declare a window soft input mode so that the keyboard does not overlap the view - instead it pushes it up.

```
<activity
   ...
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible"> ... </activity>
```

stateVisible: "The soft keyboard is visible when that's normally appropriate (when the user is navigating forward to the activity's main window)."

adjustResize: "The activity's main window is always resized to make room for the soft keyboard on screen."

[Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

That should work for you. It could be possible, depending on your views, for that to result in a poor UI and UX. If that is true, you could set a focus listener on the search view and, when it gains focus, programmatically set the state of the bottom sheet to expanded. See the answer[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35937453/set-state-of-bottomsheetdialogfragment-to-expanded).